# Class objects collection with nested Dictionary. Error: Object variable not set (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary, collections

I have some **Winners** list. Winners have their **Names** and **Presents Budget**:

[image]

---

And I have some **Presents** with their **Prices**:

[image]

---

Need to create **Class Objects Collection**. Class Object has fields:

```
Public SellerName As String   'Winner name
Public Presents As Scripting.Dictionary   'Dictionary of assigned presents
Public FillLevel As Long   'Total price of his presents
```

---

So each Class Object stores `Winner name`, his `presents as Dictionary` and `total price` of his presents.

[image]

Each winner's presents dictionary should store as much presents as it doesn't exceeds his budget.

- For example Winner1 have only one element in his Presents Dictionary.
- Winner2 have 3 elements is his Presents Dictionary. And both within Budget.
- Each winner receives presents starting from the highest price.

---

So as a result I have Objects Collection of 3 winners (3 elements in Collection).

---

**Code:**

```
Sub DistributePrize()
    
    Dim winnersList As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim presentsList As New Scripting.Dictionary
        
    'some test data for Winners Dictionary
    winnersList.Add "Winner1", 25000
    winnersList.Add "Winner2", 15000
    winnersList.Add "Winner3", 5000
    
    'some test data for Presents Dictionary
    presentsList.Add "Present1", 25000
    presentsList.Add "Present2", 10000
    presentsList.Add "Present3", 3000
    presentsList.Add "Present4", 2000
    
    'Just sorting presentsList in xlDescending order.      
    Set presentsList = SortDictionaryByValue(presentsList, xlDescending)
            
    Dim winnerKey, presentsKey As Variant
    Dim objectsCollection As New Collection
    Dim EachPresentDict As New Scripting.Dictionary
    
    Dim totalSum As Long
    
    For Each winnerKey In winnersList
    totalSum = 0      
        For Each presentsKey In presentsList
            If EachPresentDict.Exists(presentsKey) = False Then
                If totalSum <= winnersList(presentsKey) Then
                    EachPresentDict.Add presentsKey, presentsList(presentsKey)
                    totalSum = totalSum + CLng(presentsList(presentsKey))
                End If
            End If
         Next presentsKey
            
         objectsCollection.Add GetSellerPresentsObject(CStr(winnerKey), EachPresentDict, CLng(totalSum))
         EachPresentDict.RemoveAll
         
    Next winnerKey
               
End Sub
```

---

Function for generating class objects:

```
Function GetSellerPresentsObject(slrname As String, prsnts As Dictionary, flevel As Long)
    Dim obj As New Class2
    obj.SellerName = slrname
    obj.Presents = prsnts
    obj.FillLevel = flevel
    Set GetSellerPresentsObject = obj
End Function
```

---

For some reason mistake:

[image]

Code seems correct, but have difficulty in this error: `Object varible or With block variable not set`

Comment: You forgot to use `Set` when assigning the presents-dictionary to the object: `Set obj.Presents = prsnts`. Hint: It helps if you mention the line that throws the error.

Comment: Thanks. But anyway appeared that my objectsCollection have wrong elements. 7 instead of 3 and wrong TotalSum. Cannot figure out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to not using the `Set` keyword, you

- refer to the wrong dictionary in your loop
- `EachPresentDict.RemoveAll` is messing up what is stored in your `obj`
- *I'm not sure what values you expect in your `obj` so you may have to adjust the loop*

***Edit:**
To show a distribution method where presents are picked in order of their entry in the presents dictionary, until the funds run out, the code has been modified to implement that logic*

Try this modification:

```
Option Explicit

Sub DistributePrize()
    
    Dim winnersList As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim presentsList As New Scripting.Dictionary
        
    'some test data for Winners Dictionary
    winnersList.Add "Winner1", 25000
    winnersList.Add "Winner2", 15000
    winnersList.Add "Winner3", 5000
    
    'some test data for Presents Dictionary
    presentsList.Add "Present1", 25000
    presentsList.Add "Present2", 10000
    presentsList.Add "Present3", 3000
    presentsList.Add "Present4", 2000
    
    'Just sorting presentsList in xlDescending order.
    'Set presentsList = SortDictionaryByValue(presentsList, xlDescending)
            
    Dim winnerKey, presentsKey As Variant
    Dim objectsCollection As New Collection
    Dim EachPresentDict As New Scripting.Dictionary
    
    Dim totalSum As Long
    
    For Each winnerKey In winnersList
    Set EachPresentDict = New Scripting.Dictionary
    totalSum = 0
        For Each presentsKey In presentsList
            If totalSum + presentsList(presentsKey) <= winnersList(winnerKey) Then
                EachPresentDict.Add presentsKey, presentsList(presentsKey)
                totalSum = totalSum + presentsList(presentsKey)
            End If
         Next presentsKey
            
         objectsCollection.Add GetSellerPresentsObject(CStr(winnerKey), EachPresentDict, CLng(totalSum))
         
    Next winnerKey
               
End Sub

Function GetSellerPresentsObject(slrname As String, prsnts As Dictionary, flevel As Long)
    Dim obj As New Class2
    obj.SellerName = slrname
    Set obj.Presents = prsnts
    obj.FillLevel = flevel
    Set GetSellerPresentsObject = obj
End Function
```

*If you prefer using the `RemoveAll` method, put it just after the **start** of your `Each WinnerKey loop`*

Comment: Thanks for answer. But when I print all elements of objectsCollection all three elements are the same Presents dictionary with 1 element only. 2nd and 3rd elements have wrong PrizeLimit amount 25000. In fact second (objectsCollection(2)) should have 3 presents and corresponding Prize limit which is 15000. Third element of objectsCollection should have 2 elements in Presents dictionary and prize limit at 5000. Well still have no idea why this code doesnt work.

Comment: @ErbaAitbayev You will need to adjust your looping logic to implement whatever logic you are using to determine how to allocate the presents. That logic is not clear to me in your question.

Comment: @ErbaAitbayev Edited to show a certain method of distribution

Answer (score 1):

### Nested Dictionary in Each Class Object Located in a Collection

**`Debug.Print` Result**

```
Winner: Winner1
Present1       25000 
1 present(s) for 25000
Winner: Winner2
Present2       10000 
Present3       3000 
Present4       2000 
3 present(s) for 15000
Winner: Winner3
Present3       3000 
Present4       2000 
2 present(s) for 5000
```

**Standard Module e.g. `Module1`**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub PrintTest()

    Dim winners As Collection: Set winners = CollWinners
    
    Dim obj As Class2, pKey As Variant
    
    For Each obj In winners
        Debug.Print "Winner: " & obj.SellerName
        For Each pKey In obj.Presents.Keys
            Debug.Print pKey, obj.Presents(pKey)
        Next pKey
        Debug.Print obj.Presents.Count & " present(s) for " & obj.FillLevel
    Next obj

End Sub
```

```vb
' Main Function
Function CollWinners() As Collection
    
    Dim winnersList As New Scripting.Dictionary
    winnersList.Add "Winner1", 25000
    winnersList.Add "Winner2", 15000
    winnersList.Add "Winner3", 5000
    
    Dim presentsList As New Scripting.Dictionary
    presentsList.Add "Present1", 25000
    presentsList.Add "Present2", 10000
    presentsList.Add "Present3", 3000
    presentsList.Add "Present4", 2000
    
    'Just sorting presentsList in xlDescending order.
    'Set presentsList = SortDictionaryByValue(presentsList, xlDescending)
    
    Dim objectsCollection As Collection: Set objectsCollection = New Collection
    
    Dim eachPresentDict As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim WinnerKey As Variant, PresentKey As Variant
    Dim WinnerValue As Long, PresentValue As Long, TotalSum As Long
    
    For Each WinnerKey In winnersList.Keys
        WinnerValue = winnersList(WinnerKey)
        TotalSum = 0
        Set eachPresentDict = New Scripting.Dictionary
        For Each PresentKey In presentsList.Keys
            PresentValue = presentsList(PresentKey)
            If PresentValue <= WinnerValue - TotalSum Then
                eachPresentDict.Add PresentKey, PresentValue
                TotalSum = TotalSum + PresentValue
            End If
        Next PresentKey
        objectsCollection.Add GetSellerPresentsObject(CStr(WinnerKey), _
            eachPresentDict, CLng(TotalSum))
    Next WinnerKey
               
    Set CollWinners = objectsCollection
               
End Function
```

```vb
' Class Object Creator
Function GetSellerPresentsObject( _
    ByVal SellerName As String, _
    ByVal Presents As Scripting.Dictionary, _
    ByVal FillLevel As Long) _
As Class2
    Dim obj As Class2: Set obj = New Class2
    obj.SellerName = SellerName
    Set obj.Presents = Presents
    obj.FillLevel = FillLevel
    Set GetSellerPresentsObject = obj
End Function
```

**Class Module `Class2`**

```
Option Explicit

Public SellerName As String   'Winner name
Public Presents As Scripting.Dictionary   'Dictionary of assigned presents
Public FillLevel As Long   'Total price of his presents
```